# Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field contents Java

Tags: java

I am not formally a java programmer, but by looking at other answers, you set the the class variables using `this.variablename`. I used the this keyword, but I still end up with the error message as the title, as indicated below. Here is where I am constructing the class:

```
public class DataProcess {
    int rows = 252; // there's actually only 252 rows in the new "Nothing.csv"
                    // file
    String[][] contents = new String[rows][7];
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("####0.00");

    public DataProcess(String filename, String[][] contents) {
        this.contents = contents;
```

And when called in main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String filename = "";
        filename = args[0];

        DataProcess dp = new DataProcess(filename, contents); <==ERROR HERE

        System.out.println(dp.isContiguousWeek("12/30/13", "1/1/14"));
        System.out.println(dp.isContiguousWeek("12/30/04", "1/3/05"));
        System.out.println(dp.isContiguousWeek("1/3/05", "1/5/05"));
        System.out.println(dp.isContiguousWeek("1/7/05", "1/10/05"));
        System.out.println(dp.isContiguousWeek("1/31/05", "2/1/05"));
        System.out.println(dp.isContiguousWeek("4/29/05", "5/2/06"));

        System.out.println(dp.find_weeks(contents)); <== ERROR HERE
    }
```

Comment: You haven't defined and initialized `contents` in `main`.

Comment: this is nonsensical because you're trying to refer to a member of an instance, contents, without having created an instance. step back and figure out what you're actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch defining contents in main seemed to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should provide a getter method inyour `DataProcess` class to give access to a non-static contents.

```
public String[][] getContents(){
    return this.contents;
}
```

Also, change the signature of the `DataProcess.find_weeks()` method and eliminate the parameter for the `String[][]` you pass to `find_weeks`. You don't need to pass the `contents`, as the instance of `DataProcess` you created in your main (dp) already has a reference to it's own `contents` object.

Finally, in your main, just invoke `dp.find_weeks()`